# When writing let $x\in A$, does this presuppose that $A$ is nonempty?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-explanation

In this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47090/let-x-in-a-beginning-a-proof-of-forall-x-in-a-if-a-were-empty) on MathOverflow, the precise meaning of "let $x\in A$" is discussed. In particular, there were a number of logicians who stated that is perfectly acceptable to write "let $x\in A$" even if $A$ might be empty. As someone without a background in formal logic, I find it a little difficult to understand what this means in the context of natural language proofs.

For instance, consider the following statement:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty metric spaces, $S\subseteq X$ and $T\subseteq Y$, and $S\times T$ is dense in the product space $X\times Y$, then $S$ is dense in $X$ and $T$ is dense in $Y$.

Here, the definition of "$S$ is dense in $X$" is "for every $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $s\in S$ such that $d(x,s)<\varepsilon$". The above statement is false without the hypothesis that $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty; for instance, if $S=X=\varnothing$, $Y=\mathbb R$, and $T=\{0\}$, then $S\times T=\varnothing$ is dense in $X\times Y=\varnothing$, but $T$ is not dense in $Y$.

The usual proof would go something like this:

> We shall show that $T$ is dense in $Y$ (the proof that $S$ is dense in $X$ is similar). Let $\varepsilon>0$, $x\in X$, and $y\in Y$. By the density of $S\times T$ in $X\times Y$, there exists $(s,t)\in S\times T$ such that $d_{X\times Y}((x,y),(s,t))<\varepsilon$. Thus, $d_Y(y,t)<\varepsilon$.

Where exactly does this proof break down in the case that $X$ is empty? I would have thought that this is when we write "let $x\in X$", but the post on MathOverflow has made me doubt this.

Comment: Your "usual proof" shows that ($\forall\varepsilon>0$):
 *for every $(x,y)\in X\times Y$*, there exists $(s,t)$ such that [...] $d_Y(y,t)<\varepsilon$.
If $X\times Y=\varnothing,$ this cannot be applied to any $(x,y),$ hence it brings you [no $(s,t)$ i.e.] no information at all.

Comment: What you mean is : "If $x\in A$, then ..." makes sense , but "Let $x\in A$" does not really make sense if $A$ is empty since no element  can be in $A$ and $x\in A$ demands that $x$ is in $A$ before we can continue.

Comment: $A$ may be empty and you may very well state $x \in A$ to show that such an assumption leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy See my answer for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we write "let $x \in A$", we could mean two different things:

- This might be part of the proof of a statement that "for all $x \in A$", some conclusion holds. In this case, we do not need to know that $A$ is nonempty to say, "we will prove that the conclusion holds for all $x \in A$ by picking an arbitrary $x \in A$ and proving the conclusion from there". This is similar to how we prove an implication $P \implies Q$ by assuming $P$ and proving $Q$: this is fine to do even if $P$ is not guaranteed to be true.
- If we pick an arbitrary element of $A$ for any *other* reason, then we need to justify that $A$ is nonempty.

In the case of the proof that $T$ is dense in $Y$, we are working with the following definition: for all $y \in Y$, we can find elements of $T$ arbitrarily close to $y$. This gives us the license to choose an arbitrary $y \in Y$. (It may also be observed that when $Y = \varnothing$, the statement that $T$ is dense in $Y$ is vacuously true.)

However, there is nothing in this step of the proof allowing us to choose an arbitrary $x \in X$, and so that step of the proof is invalid.

(We do get a valid proof that if $S \subseteq X$, $T \subseteq Y$, $X$ is nonempty, and $S\times T$ is dense in $X \times Y$, then $T$ is dense in $Y$.)

Comment: +1, this is a beautiful subtlety that I have never thought of before, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your "usual proof" shows that ($\forall\varepsilon>0$):

> *for every $(x,y)\in X\times Y$*, there exists $(s,t)$ such that [...] $d_Y(y,t)<\varepsilon$.

If $X\times Y=\varnothing,$ this cannot be applied to any $(x,y),$ hence it brings you [no $(s,t)$ i.e.] no information at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is helpful to write down the precise logical statement you have proven. What you have proven is the following:

$$\forall x\in X[\forall y\in Y[  \exists t\in T(d_{ Y}(y,t)<\epsilon)]]$$

which is the same as:
$$\forall x[x\in X \to [\forall y\in Y[\exists t\in T(d_{Y}(y,t)<\epsilon)]]$$

***What you want to prove*** is that $$\forall y\in Y[  \exists t\in T(d_{ Y}(y,t)<\epsilon)]$$
You can do this **as long as you have a witness** belonging to $X$ by the principal of existential intiation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible for you to elaborate on how you would use the principle to existential instantiation to *formally* deduce the bottom statement in the case that $X$ is nonempty?